# Does this imply a mutually exclusive relationship?

Tags: meaning

"The process of successfully growing into the world requires negotiation between hard work and new pathways"

are 'hard work' and 'pathways' implied to be mutually exclusive by this statement

Comment: If they were mutually exclusive there could be no compromise.

Comment: @Robusto I changed the word check again

Comment: If a Yes or No is being sought, I would say Yes.  The way this sentence is put together suggests that *hard work* is at one end of an axis and *new pathways* is at the other, so you have to do some trial and error to find the right in-between point.  //  I have to say, the sentence doesn't make much sense to me, especially "growing into the world".  It would be very helpful if you could provide the context for the question.  Perhaps you are taking a practice test where you are supposed to analyze some provided sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence implies that some degree of antithetical tension obtains between the two, so as to make compromise necessary; but as Robusto notes, their being *mutually exclusive* would make such compromise impossible.

OP’s substitution of the term *negotiation* for *compromise* does not make a huge difference here.

Let us posit tropical vacations as *opportunity* for enjoyment, and forgoing them so as to save money for retirement as *sacrifice.* A wise person might compromise or negotiate between the two, by taking one such tropical vacation per year instead of three or none. That way, one hopes, retirement can be adequately provided for, but pleasure enjoyed also. (This may be wisdom in that one may not live to retire, and should taste of pleasure while alive; but yet penury in age is a great and preventable evil.) This compromise would combine some of either element, proving them *not* “mutually exclusive.”

Comment: thank you, but if the statement was between sacrifice for oppt. would that then imply mutually exclusive?

Comment: Between "sacrifice for opportunity" and what else?

Comment: that's it i.e. replace the 'and' with the 'for

Comment: ‘Gladstone spent his declining years trying to guess the answer to the Irish question; unfortunately, whenever he was getting warm, the Irish secretly changed the question.’  --from Sellar and Yeatman's *1066 and All That.*

Comment: Substituting *for* for *and* is not a valid move; *between* requires for object a coordinate pair of alternatives.